# Compile errors when setting up Plone development environment

Tags: themes, plone, plone-5.x

I'm trying to follow the walkthrough here to produce a new theme for my Plone 5.1 server:

https://training.plone.org/5/theming/theme-package.html

I'm using MacOS 10.13.6 running clang clang-1000.11.45.5 (the one that comes with XCode) and Python 3.6.4 (installed through Anaconda).  I've run into some trouble since the buildout script that is produced by mr.bob doesn't appear to contain all of the dependencies, specifically `plone.recipe.zope2instance==4.2.22`.  When I attempt to install that dependency manually, I get the following compilation error:

```
src/Persistence/_Persistence.c:178:5: error: non-void function 'init_Persistence' should return a value [-Wreturn-type]
    return;
    ^
17 warnings and 7 errors generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried upgrading to the latest version of mr.bob and the templates, then using the plonecli to create and start the buildout, but I get the same compilation errors.

There are many like it in that module.  How do I resolve this so I can finish installing that dependency and finish my buildout?

Comment: Please consider asking Plone questions in our forum https://community.plone.org where more of us will see them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plone is using Python 2.7.x until Version 5.1.
In Plone 5.2 you will have the option to run Plone under Python 3, but then you have to use the WSGI-Server instead of the ZServer. For now just use Plone 5.1 with Python 2.7 as Plone 5.2 is still not finally released.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use Python 2.7, it's better supported by Zope and Plone.

Comment: Python 2.7 is required for Plone, up to and including Plone 5.1.x.

Comment: I thought it was working, but when I ran buildout, I got the error `ContextualVersionConflict: (Zope2 2.13.28 (/anaconda3/envs/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('Zope2>=4.0a5'), set(['Products.ZCatalog', 'Products.BTreeFolder2', 'Products.StandardCacheManagers']))`